# How to call list objects inside another class

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I have an object of list inside class named `Scorer.java` and i want to import `aLinks` and `bLinks` objects in another class named `MyParser.java` to get print `aLinks.size()` and `bLinks.size()` i tried to import class name first the call the object but i could not do that. Can you tell me how to import the objects of lists from class to another? Here are the classes:

My `Scorer.java`:

```
 public class Scorer {
 public static List<LinkNode> score(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNode> links){

 List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>();
 List<LinkNode> bLinks = new LinkedList<>();

    for (LinkNode link : links) {
        if(isbLink(sourceLink, link)) { 
            bLinks.add(link);
        } else {
            aLinks.add(link);
        }
    }
```

My other class `MyParser.java`

```
public class MyParser {
private static final String[] PARSE_TAGS = new String[]{"a[href", "area[href"};


public static List<LinkNode> parse(LinkNode inputLink){
    Set<LinkNode> outputLinks = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    try {
         Document parsedResults = Jsoup
                .connect(inputLink.getUrl())
                .timeout(READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
                .get();

        String tag;
        Elements elements;
        List<LinkNode> result;

        //a[href
        tag = "a[href";
        elements = parsedResults.select(tag);
        result = toLinks(inputLink, elements, tag);
        outputLinks.addAll(result);

        // I want to print `aLinks.size()` and `bLinks.size()` here

    } 

    return new LinkedList<>(outputLinks);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call

```
   MyParser myparser = new MyParser (); 
   myparser.parse(scorerInstance.getAlinks());
   myparser.parse(scorerInstance.getBlinks());
```

Where `scorerInstance` is an instance of MyScorer. You should add getters for `aLinks` and `bLinks` in `MyScorer` Class like this:

```
 public List<LinkNode> getALinks() {
      return  aLinks;
  }

 public List<LinkNode> getBLinks() {
      return  bLinks;
  }
```

Comment: `aLinks` and `bLinks` are instance variables in the (static) method `score`. This is not going to work.

Comment: Sorry but still getting error: Illegal modifier for parameter aLinks; only final is permitted and error: Illegal modifier for parameter bLinks; only final is permitted @Master Mind

Comment: Thanks again. At first time i added it inside `Scorer` class inside `Score` list and get this error. After that i added it outside of `Score` list with `public static` method and its works fine now. I just wonderis that affect my program since i brings `aLinks` and `bLinks` line codes outside of `score` list ? @MasterMind

Comment: It's better design to make them inside Score if they belong to it. Otherwise, no.

Comment: So the code will get me not real results? So how can i pass the object of list without any change in my `score` list or bringing it out side `score` list? I mean i want to leave `aLinks` and `bLinks` inside `score` list ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76722/discussion-between-master-mind-and-medo0070).

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the needed variables as global and `public` and also `static` in `Scorer` class

```
 public class Scorer {

 public static List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>();
 public static List<LinkNode> bLinks = new LinkedList<>();
 public static List<LinkNode> score(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNode> links){

    for (LinkNode link : links) {
        if(isbLink(sourceLink, link)) { 
            bLinks.add(link);
        } else {
            aLinks.add(link);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Then in `MyParser` class, call class_name .(dot) static_variable .

Then try this in `MyParser` class:

```
System.out.println(Scorer.aLinks.size()+ " " + Scorer.bLinks.size());
```

Comment: `score()` is a static method. This is not going to work.

Comment: I could not do it. I've got: illegal modifier for parameter only final is permitted. I cpuld not write public in front of the code @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan

Comment: @medo0070 that is because you did not move the definition out of the method and turn it into a field. You have to put it outside the method definition.

Answer (score 2):

If the classes are in different packages, you will need to make alinks public. But you will also need to make it static and turn it into a field of the class

```
public class Scorer {
    public static List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then you can access it as `Scorer.alinks`

Comment: Thank you for your help but it does not work. The program is not allow me to add `public static` in front of List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>(); it said: `illegal modifier for parameter only final is permitted` @Evan Williams

Comment: @medo0070 Move the line out of the method and directly under `public class Scorer {` as I did in my answer.

Comment: Thank you its work now but i wander to ask is this will affect my program ? i mean in my lins `List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>(); ` and `List<LinkNode> bLinks = new LinkedList<>();` is inside `List<LinkNode> score(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNode> links)` since `score` is collecting my `aLinks` and `bLinks` ? @Evan Williams

Comment: @medo0070 it depends on what behavior you want. If you want a fresh aLinks and bLinks every time you run `score`, you need to initialize them each time (don't declare them again!). So you would add `aLinks = new LinkedList<>();` and `bLinks = new LinkedList<>();` to the top of your `score` method and delete the ` = new LinkedList<>()` from where the variables aredeclared, so the declarations would look like `public static List<LinkNode> aLinks;` and `public static List<LinkNode> bLinks`

Comment: I did what you said but getting error after a while of running. I think i will leave it as it was before deleting ` = new LinkedList<>()` . My `score list` in the top of `aLinks` and `bLinks` will collect the information from both of `aLinks` and `bLinks` and add them to a `single list`. So if i get them outside of `score` list as i write in my question. Will that get me not real or not expected results ? Thanks alot @Evan Williamas

Answer (score 1):

First of all `aLinks` and `bLinks` should be member of the `Scorer` class and should not be declared inside a method of the class.

Like this:

```
public class Scorer {
    public List<LinkNode> aLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    public List<LinkNode> bLinks = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

Secondly, you have to get a `Scorer` object in `MyParser` class. Then you can access `aLinks` and `BLinks`. This should be like this:

```
Scorer myScorer = new Scorer();
System.out.println(myScorer.aLinks().size());
System.out.println(myScorer.bLinks().size());
```

This should be added in place of the commented section in your `MyParser` class.

Thirdly, if your `score` method is static then you should have an instance of the `Score` class in your `score` method as well. You can pass that instance to `score` method. Like this:

```
public static List<LinkNode> score(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNode> links, Score myScore){
    //myScore.aLinks or myScore.bLinks can be used here
}
```

Comment: `score()` is a static method. This is not going to work.

Comment: Oh! I missed it. Let me edit the code. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I've got error, I could not add "Public" in front of the code it said: illegal modifier for parameter only final is permitted @soham.m17

Comment: so aLinks and bLinks are static, hence you could make the getters  `getBLinks() `  static

Comment: Where did you write those declarations? Is it inside your score method? If yes, then it should be added outside the method as member of Score class.

Comment: At first time i added it inside `Scorer` class inside `Score` list and get this error. After that i added it outside of `Score` list with `public static` method and its works fine now. I just wonderis that affect my program since i brings `aLinks` and `bLinks` line codes outside of `score` list ? @soham.m17

Comment: Okay. First things first. `score` is not a list, it's a method. `Scorer` is a class. When you add those two declaration statements inside your `score` function, you cannot have those variables as public. That's why I told you to add those outside the `score` method. Now I didn't tell you to make them `static`. As you have made them `static`, the lists are same for all the objects you create for `Scorer` class. If you have `myScorerChemistry` and `myScorerPhysics`, they both will have the same `aLinks` and `bLinks` and not different. If that's what you want, then go ahead.